# How to change default data directory in MonetDB?

Tags: directory, monetdb

I am trying to change the default data directory of MonetDB. I am running out of space, and I would like to migrate the data to another folder.
Does anyone know how to do that?

I have installed MonetDB using the ubuntu package, and by default the data is stored in:

```
/var/lib/monetdb
```

I would welcome a solution that doesn't involve compiling MonetDB from source...

Answer (score 1):

MonetDB data could reside anywhere. You could move the path to farm anywhere you like and just  to provide the path to monetdbd while loading.

Refer: http://www.monetdb.org/Documentation/UserGuide/Tutorial

**1) monetdbd create /path/to/mydbfarm 

2) monetdbd start /path/to/mydbfarm**